# Manually adding Magento EE admin user via SQL

Tags: sql, admin, enterprise

I have a Magento Enterprise install. I now need to create an admin user via SQL because the other webmaster is not available. So to get access the only thing I can think of is since I have sql access is to manually create an admin user. I found the below sql which should create a user. However it does not work. When I enter the credentials "USERNAME" and the password "PASSWORD" the login page just reloads and I looked in the Magento var/log and no error is generated. I know using the above username and password is not the most secure. However I figure once I login I will then update the password etc.  Any suggestions what I am missing?

```
insert into admin_user
 select (select max(user_id) + 1 from admin_user) user_id,
         'FIRSTNAME' first_name,
         'LASTNAME' last_name,
         'TEST@EMAIL.COM' email,
         'USERNAME' username,
         MD5('PASSWORD') password,
         now() created,
         NULL modified,
         NULL logdate,
         0 lognum,
         0 reload_acl_flag,
         1 is_active,
         (select max(extra) from admin_user where extra is not null) extra,
          NULL,
          NULL;
```

insert into admin_user
select
(select max(user_id) + 1 from admin_user) user_id,
'FIRSTNAME' first_name,
'LASTNAME' last_name,
'TEST@EMAIL.COM' email,
'USERNAME' username,
MD5('PASSWORD') password,
now() created,
NULL modified,
NULL logdate,
0 lognum,
0 reload_acl_flag,
1 is_active,
(select max(extra) from admin_user where extra is not null) extra,
NULL,
NULL;

```
insert into admin_role
 select(select max(role_id) + 1 from admin_role) role_id,
        (select role_id from admin_role where role_name = 'Administrators')               
         parent_id,
         2 tree_level,
         0 sort_order,
         'U' role_type,
          (select user_id from admin_user where username = 'USERNAME')     user_id,
        'USERNAME' role_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google Chrome please try to clear cookies and reload login page.